# CopyAllViews = false is being ignored by SMO

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, smo

I want SMO to not script the views so I do this

```
 var transfer = new Transfer(database)
    {
        CopyAllTables = true,
        CopyAllDefaults = false,
        CopyAllStoredProcedures = true,
        CopyAllDatabaseTriggers = true,
        CopyAllObjects = false,
        CopyAllPartitionFunctions = false,
        CopyAllPartitionSchemes = false,
        CopyAllRoles = false,
        CopyAllRules = true,
        CopyAllSchemas = true,
        CopyAllSqlAssemblies = false,
        CopyAllSynonyms = false,
        CopyAllUserDefinedAggregates = true,
        CopyAllUserDefinedDataTypes = true,
        CopyAllUserDefinedFunctions = true,
        CopyAllUserDefinedTypes = true,
        CopyAllUsers = false,
        CopyAllViews = false,
        Options =
        {
            WithDependencies = true,
            DriAll = true,
            Triggers = true,
            Indexes = true,
            SchemaQualifyForeignKeysReferences = true,
            ExtendedProperties = true,
            IncludeDatabaseRoleMemberships = false,
            Permissions = true,
            IncludeDatabaseContext = true
        },
        PreserveDbo = true,
    };

    transfer.ScriptTransfer()
```

but the views are still scripted.

I really want to be able to use transfer as it seems to be the only way to get the objects scripted in dependency order without writing more code. I set 
"CopyAllObjects = false" because I thought maybe that was causing the rest of the options that I had set to be ignored, but it didn't seem to do any good.

My goal here is to script out the views separately because I have a database server with views that depend on each other and will need to use dependencywalker on the views in all databases to script them in dependency order.

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly fix it but ended up filtering out any lines with "create view" in them. so I just call

```
 transfer.ScriptTransfer().Cast<string>().ToList()
```

unless I am missing something, a lot of these flags (like CopyAllUsers) in the options SMO seems to only honor when it feels like it. :( it's a shame when some options looks exactly like what I need but do not work.